# Is it possible to see the complete request JMeter is making?

Tags: url, curl, get, jmeter, connection-timeout

I have a jmeter test running and its simply outputting response codes (all connection timed out). The requests work when I use curl form the box. I want to see what URL it is hitting to be sure. Anyway to see what URL the GET request is actually failing on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `View Results Tree` listener in your test?
It can show the URL & other details It sent.

[image]

Note:  This listener consumes more memory. Just use it for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure JMeter to store more info in *jmeter.log* file by adding the following line to "user.properties" file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
log_level.jmeter.protocol.http=DEBUG
```

You'll get output like:

```
2015/04/09 11:20:26 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Start : sample http://example.com/ 
2015/04/09 11:20:26 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: method GET followingRedirect false depth 0 
2015/04/09 11:20:26 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Created new HttpClient: @563504346 http://example.com 
2015/04/09 11:20:26 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: ResponseHeadersSize=321 Content-Length=1270 Total=1591 
2015/04/09 11:20:26 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Thread Finished
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on different JMeter properties types and ways of setting/overriding them.